# Windows Start-button Shortcut in the OSX Citrix Receiver

Tags: macos, shortcuts, citrix

Within CoRD, and even VMware View, hitting `Command ⌘` results in the Start-button shortcut being passed to Windows. Within the Citrix receiver, by default this isn't the case.

What's the best way of enabling it?

Thank you